# Remotely Image a Windows Server

Tags: windows, remote-access, image, imaging

I have a couple windows servers that I do not have physical access to, but I have remote log in access to.  I need to pull down am image of these machine as a backup, what would be the best method of doing this?

Comment: What version of Windows Server are you running?

Comment: I am not sure, the person who owns the servers doesnt really know. I have not gotten the remote access from him yet

Comment: The server is Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Windows Server 2008, it has built-in backup capabilities that can image the computer while it's running. Open a command prompt and run wbadmin /? for more information. There's also [the official TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754015(WS.10).aspx) on the tool. As to how to remotely run it, have a look at [WinRM/WinRS](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/How-Windows-Server-2008-WinRM-WinRS.html) which is built in to 2008 and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

I've touted this product on here before, but I'll say it again. [ShadowProtect Server](http://storagecraft.com) If you can get some type of attached storage connected to the server, you can take an online image of the box. The software simply works.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to store a backup (image)? May be [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.eu/enterprise/) will be good for you.

**Advanced backup scheduling**
**Live disk snapshots with support for databases and server applications**
**Recover an entire system, single file or folder**
**Advanced encryption technology ensures data security**
**Optimized, image-based backup technology maximizes backup performance**

If you want to use an external storage - Script + Windows Task Manager + Ftp (Another storage)

Answer (score 0):

We used VMWare Converter to create backups of our hosted servers, it gave us the images as VMs. For a once-off project it was very convenient.

Comment: Have you tried performing a restore of those images? Without the ability to restore to the original machine it's not really a backup.

Comment: they were hosted servers that we had no access to, so a physical restore was not our goal. We could start the images in the free VMware ESX environment and access the data, or re-config them and put them on our own internet connection if we had to.   After playing with virtual servers we may never bare-metal install an operating sys again, the backup and migration process means never feeding cds into a server again.

Answer (score 0):

[Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) is a free tool from Microsoft Sysinternals that can create a full backup image of a running server, including the system partition.  It works with Server 2003 as well as Server 2008.

I have never tried to restore such an image to bare metal; to try, one would want identical hardware and a tool that can copy a VHD back to a physical disk (e.g. Acronis True Image) or enough Linux-fu to convert it into a raw image and then copy it to a physical disk with dd.  Your mileage may vary.  I *have* restored many such images to Hyper-V servers, and that works beautifully.

Comment: I would be very surprised if it could restore the original machine. This is pretty much the same thing as james suggested with VWMare Converter.